# How can i read the first XML comment in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

How can I read the first and only comment in PHP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- read this -->
<root>
</root>
```

using DOMDOcument object?

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();

$libxml_error = 'Il file %s non risulta ben formato (%s).';

// Per evitare i warning nel caso di xml non ben formato occorre sopprimere
// gli errori
if (!@$xml -> load($xml_file_path)) $error = sprintf($libxml_error,
    $xml_file_path, libxml_get_last_error()->message);

// Read the fist comment in xml file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    var_dump($comment->textContent);
}
```

Since you probably only want the first one:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$results = $xpath->query('//comment()');
$comment = $results[0];
var_dump($comment);
```

**Source**: [How to retrieve comments from within an XML Document in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986764/how-to-retrieve-comments-from-within-an-xml-document/1987555#1987555)

Comment: Fine. Why not //comment()[1]?

Comment: Since `DOMXPath::query` always returns a list of nodes. Basically, even when you would query `...[1]`, you still got an array-like object (so you still needed to add an additional `$comments = $results[0];` line). **Source**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0):

How to get the comments from XML file - look for instructions here:

[How to retrieve comments from within an XML Document in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986764/how-to-retrieve-comments-from-within-an-xml-document)