# Get HTML comment from $p->nodeValue possible with DomXPath?

Tags: php, domparser

I have several HTML paragraphs like this (always same structure):

```
<p>
    <!-- Gl. 1-4 -->
    \( x(t) = x_0 · t^3 \)
    [!equanchor? &id=`555`!]
</p>
```

I am extracting the `555` successfully by:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$paragraphs = $xpath->query('//p');
foreach($paragraphs as $p)
{
    $ptext = $p->nodeValue;
    if(strpos($ptext, 'equanchor') !== false)
    {
        // get equation id from anchor
        preg_match('/equanchor\?\s\&id=`(.*)\`/', $ptext, $matches);
        $equationids[] = (int)$matches[1];
    }
}
```

Now I would also need the text from the **HTML comment**, which is `<!-- Gl. 1-4 -->`, but I couldn't find out how to use the DOM parser (DomXPath) for this purpose. Unfortunately, the `$p->nodeValue` nor the `$p->textContent` do contain the comment text.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987555/1066234) did not help me. I tried a "sub parser" but it failed to read the `$ptext` or `$p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `comment()` XPath function (from [Accessing Comments in XML using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784745/accessing-comments-in-xml-using-xpath)).

So in your case, when you want to get the comment in the `<p>` tag, you can just add the line...

```
echo $dom->saveHTML($xpath->query("comment()", $p)[0]);
```

in your `foreach` loop (this fetches the comment node within the `$p` element in your loop).  Using `[0]` to get the first one (assuming only one).

Which outputs...

```
<!-- Gl. 1-4 -->
```

Comment: Lovely. Thanks a lot! I had never got the idea to use `saveHTML()` for this. PS: Added a simple `$comment = str_replace(['<!-- ', '-->'], '', $comment);` to get the inner text with "Gl. 1-4".

Comment: If you just need the content `$comment = $xpath->query("comment()", $p)[0]->textContent;` may be neater.

Comment: Does not work within the `saveHTML()` function. But the solution is fantastic enough already :)

Comment: `textContent` is a property of the DOMNode node, so you don't need to convert it back to HTML.